# Display number of checked checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am quite new to jQuery, I think this might be quite easy for many of you, but I can't seem to make it work. How can I display the number of checkboxes so that the value increases or decreases.

i tried the following but with the number in the span tag remains 0: http://jsfiddle.net/yunowork/NTwxc/

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should listen to the `change` event:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    var number = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    $('.totalchecked').text(number);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NTwxc/7/

Note that `val` is used for getting/setting values of form elements, for other elements like span element, `text` or `html` methods should be used.

Comment: IIRC `('input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function () { /* ... */ });` is the preffered way for registering the event handler.

Comment: @apfelbox Why do you think that is preferred?

Comment: I read it here: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/ "All the existing event binding methods (and their corresponding unbinding methods) are still there in 1.7, but we recommend that you use .on() for any new jQuery project where you know version 1.7 or higher is in use." I have no knowledge, why they preferr `.on()`, but they say it.

Comment: @apfelbox Yes, for event delegation `on` is preferred, but here elements are static.

Comment: The blog post does not mention event delegation in particular, but rather all event binding. See the list of examples below the quoted line. `.change()` is the short form of `.bind("change")`, which is now superseded by `.on("change")`. They write themselves: `.change()` does only still exist for BC reasons.

Comment: @apfelbox Okay, I have updated the code, but change is not deprecated :).

Comment: I just looked up the definition of `.change()` [on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L1011). Basically it is `jQuery.fn["change"] = function( data, fn ) { return this.on( "change", null, data, fn ); };`

Answer (score 0):

Number of checked checkboxes:

```
$(":checkbox:checked").length
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

---

*edit: I see in your fiddle that you already had that. I'll leave it there, since that's actually the answer to "how to display the number of checked checkboxes"...*

The problem is that you're not updating and looking to see how many are checked. You need to re-run that function whenever any of the items are checked.

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
    // update the span with $(":checkbox:checked").length ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be setting `.val` of a span, but `.text`.

Also, you need to update it every time the checked state changes.

```
function calc() {
    $('.totalchecked').text($(':checkbox:checked').length);
}

$(calc);
$(':checkbox').change(calc);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x38S2/)

Comment: Ideally, one should use `.text()`, when not inserting HTML.

Comment: @apfelbox: I'll agree with that. Updated.

Comment: @scr4ve: for running `calc` immediately on DOMReady. Passing a function to `$()` is short for `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

Problems: `.val()` is for form elements only. To set the content of an element, use `.text()` or `.html()` if you are inserting HTML. Second problem is that you need to register a listener to "change" events. Otherwise, the value won't update.

Updated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/NTwxc/4/

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
    var number = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    $(".totalchecked").text(number);
});
​
```

By the way, I would personally prefer `input[type=checkbox]`rather than `:checkbox`. The former works for both CSS and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are!

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

        $('.totalchecked').empty().text($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').size());
    });
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/PTvG8/**